# How can I mock dependencies of a factory in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, chutzpah

I'm trying ti do a unit test for my AngularJs app, using [Chutzpah](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/71a4e9bd-f660-448f-bd92-f5a65d39b7f0) in VS2013.
Let's say I have this factory:

```
myAppModule.factory('MyService',function(){
  var fact = {};
  fact.myFunction = function(){
    return "Hello";
  };
});
```

I wrote the unit test for it like this:

```
describe("TestService-Test", function () {
   var service;

    beforeEach(function () {

    module('myApp');

    inject(function ($injector) {
        service = $injector.get('MyService');
    });
});
```

This works fine, but if I added to the same service just one dependency (or more):

```
myAppModule.factory('MyService',function($scope){ ... etc the same
```

Even if I didn't use $scope, this will throw an exception when run the test in VS2013 using [Chutzpah](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/71a4e9bd-f660-448f-bd92-f5a65d39b7f0), and the exception says:

> Result Message:   Error: [$injector:unpr] ... etc

As I understood from this error it's about not be able to identify the service I'm asking for.

I need to be able to inject some dependencies in the service creation, but how to do it ?

If I did the same with the controller It'll work like a charm because, it has a clear way to inject the dependencies while creating the controller using the service `$controller`.

**PS:**
At the top of test js file I'm including those references:

```
/// <reference path="../js/angular.min.js" />
/// <reference path="../js/angular-mocks.js" />
/// <reference path="../js/myAppFile.js" />
/// <reference path="../js/myServiceFile.js" />
```

Comment: Sorry it's not an issue, as I saw that I can't even inject $scope in factory because it's not a provider.
I tried it with $http and $rootScope providers and it did work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the same question that was cross posted on the [Chutzpah github page](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/issues/401). The resolution there was posted by the same original poster:

> Sorry it's not an issue, as I saw that I can't even inject $scope in
>   factory because it's not a provider. I tried it with $http and
>   $rootScope providers and it did work.

Comment: yes right and I posted a comment under the question to clarify the solution, I'll post it as an answer too

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it's not an issue, as I saw that I can't even inject `$scope` in factory because it's not a provider. I tried it with `$http` and `$rootScope` providers and it did work